# Expository problems

Tags: soft-question

In one article on his [blog](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/a-solution-to-an-exposition-problem); T. Gowers talks about ''expository problems''.

For those too lazy to click that link, a quote of a quote:

> Solving an open exposition problem means explaining a mathematical subject in a way that renders it totally perspicuous. Every step should be motivated and clear; ideally, students should feel that they could have arrived at the results themselves.

I'm sure that all of us can value good **solutions** to expository problems, and that all of us were sometimes really frustrated by some expository problems.

So, what *expository problems* do you know? What's that one thing in math you could never intuitively grasp? If you are a member of faculty, have you ever noticed some topics in your field which are particularly hard to *get* for your students (and you don't really get why)?

P.S. I'm sorry if this question is too ''soft'' for math.stackexchange, but I think it's really interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I never understood intuitively why pi is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two statements:

> $\bullet$ The ring $\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z$ has 4 elements but is not a field.
>    $\bullet \bullet$ There exists a field with 4 elements.

I have noticed year after year that it is quite  difficult for students to believe that both can be true simultaneously.

The remedy is to describe the field very explicitly as $$\mathbb F_4=\frac {\mathbb F_2[X]}{\langle X^2+X+1\rangle}=\lbrace 0,1,x,1+x \rbrace $$

The expository problem might be to make crystal-clear what these cabalistic equalities mean and  why this $\mathbb F_4$ is indeed a field with four elements.
And then to explain why the use of $\mathbb F_2$ and $X^2+X+1$ on the road leading to $\mathbb F_4$ is the kernel of the "bootstrapping" method , which allows us to construct a big  finite field $K$ from a small finite field $k$ by taking an irreducible polynomial $f(X)\in k[X]$ and building the quotient $$K=k[X]/\langle f(X)\rangle$$.